# How to pass hovered - over element data to another function and use its data- attributes

Tags: jquery, events, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to make my own dropdown menu for my ASP.NET MVC application. The best idea that I can think of is to have submenus in divs and show/hide them when hovering over the base menus. As there'll be multiple submenus I have to decide which one to show and which ones to hide according to the base menu item hovered-over. For that I have added data- attributes to all of the base menu items:

```
<div data-index=0 class="menu-base">Menu1</div>
<div data-index=1 class="menu-base">Menu1</div>
<div data-index=2 class="menu-base">Menu1</div>
<div data-index=3 class="menu-base">Menu1</div>
```

I use jquery [mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events to hide/show the submenus. And I have a function called showSubMenu where all this process takes place:

```
function showSubMenu(currentBaseMenu){
   var index=somehow get the value of data-index attribute;
   switch index 
     case:........
}
```

So I need to pass information about the menu item (in this case div) to the showSubMenu function to be able to know which sub menu to show. I've tried the following:

```
  1. $('.menu-base').mouseenter(showSubMenu(e));//This throws an exception "e is undefined"
  2. $('.menu-base').mouseenter(function(e){showSubMenu(e);})
          function showSubMenu(menu){
              alert($(menu));//Alerts [Object object]
              alert($(menu).attr('data-index'));//Alerts undefined
      }
```

So what is the proper way of sending the information about the element the event got triggered on to another function? And how to get the custom data- attribute value out of that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` in the event handler is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), `this` will refer to the element targeted by the handler so

```
$('.menu-base').mouseenter(function (e) {
    showSubMenu(this);
})

function showSubMenu(menu) {
    console.log($(menu)); //Alerts [Object object]
    console.log($(menu).attr('data-index')); //Alerts undefined
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6fwucm1w/)

Comment: The fiddle you provided does not work. I mean when I hover over the menus nothing happens

Comment: @MikeJM I changed the alert to console logging... so check your [browser console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: Huh, sorry, I didn't notice console. Cool, that does indeed work. Don't know why I didn't try "this".